# Resizing .nii file in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, rescale, mri, nilearn

I am trying to resize Nii files so that my program takes less computational resources, I want to rescale them from (240,240,155) to (120,120,155). I have tried using nilearn.image.resample_img module to do so however as it is seen the image below the output is not what I would expect. Need some help to figure this out. [image]

Comment: Can you use `pillow`? Resizing an image is easy there: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html?highlight=resize#PIL.Image.Image.resize

Comment: @Dabhi *"I have tried using nilearn.image.resample_img module"* would you please share what you have tried so far as a piece of code? [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Dabhi please take a look into this [solution](https://neurostars.org/t/nibabel-how-can-we-rescale-a-3d-image/4107/2)

Comment: The documentation in `nilearn` says that if you give a new size, the image will be cropped or padded. For actual resampling you need to change the spacing (via the affine transform).

Comment: I am not sure how to use the affine transform to resize image. Could you point to an example?